# Using ggplotly rangeslider for interactive relative performance (stock returns)

Tags: r, dplyr, r-plotly, ggplotly, rangeslider

I am trying to make an interactive stock performance plot from R. It is to compare the relative performance of several stocks. Each stock's performance line should start at 0%.

For static plots I would use dplyr `group_by` and `mutate` to calculate performance (see my code).

With ggplot2 and plotly/ggplotly, `rangeslider()` allows to interactively select the x-axis range. Now I'd like performance to be starting at 0 from any start range selected.

How can I either move the dplyr calculation into the plotting or have a feedback loop to recalculate as the range is changed?

Ideally it should be usable in static RMarkdown HTML. Alternatively I'd also switch to Shiny.

I tried several [options for rangeslider](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-rangeslider). Also I tried with ggplot `stat_function` but could not achieve the desired result. Also I found [dygraphs](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/) which has `dyRangeSelector`. But also here I face the same problem.

This is my code:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyquant)

stocks <- tq_get(c("AAPL", "MSFT"), from = "2019-01-01")

range_from <- as.Date("2019-02-01")

stocks_range <- stocks %>% 
  filter(date >= range_from) %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  mutate(performance = adjusted/first(adjusted)-1)

p <- stocks_range %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = performance, color = symbol)) +
  geom_line()

ggplotly(p, dynamicTicks = T) %>%
  rangeslider(borderwidth = 1) %>%
  layout(hovermode = "x", yaxis = list(tickformat = "%"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use `shiny`, you can either use the `dyRebase` option in `dygraphs`, or you have to insert custom `javascript` code in `plotly`. In both examples, I rebase to one, not zero.

Option 1: with `dygraphs`

```
library(dygraphs)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(tidyr)

stocks <- tq_get(c("AAPL", "MSFT"), from = "2019-01-01")

stocks %>% 
  dplyr::select(symbol, date, adjusted) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(key = symbol, value = adjusted) %>% 
  timetk::tk_xts() %>% 
  dygraph() %>%
  dyRebase(value = 1) %>% 
  dyRangeSelector()
```

Note that `dyRebase(value = 0) does not work.

Option 2: with `plotly` using [event handlers](https://plotly-r.com/js-event-handlers.html). I try to avoid `ggplotly`, hence my `plot_ly` solution. Here the time selection is just by zooming, but I think it can be done by a range selector as well. The `javascript` code in `onRenderRebaseTxt` rebases every trace to the first visible data point (taking care of possible missing values). It is only called with the `relayout` event, hence the first rebasing must be done before the plot.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(dplyr)

stocks <- tq_get(c("AAPL", "MSFT"), from = "2019-01-01")

pltly <- 
  stocks %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(symbol) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(adjusted = adjusted / adjusted[1L]) %>% 
  plotly::plot_ly(x = ~date, y = ~adjusted, color = ~symbol,
                  type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>% 
  plotly::layout(dragmode = "zoom", 
                 datarevision = 0)

onRenderRebaseTxt <- "
  function(el, x) {
el.on('plotly_relayout', function(rlyt) {
        var nrTrcs = el.data.length;
        // array of x index to rebase to; defaults to zero when all x are shown, needs to be one per trace
        baseX = Array.from({length: nrTrcs}, (v, i) => 0);
        // if x zoomed, increase baseX until first x point larger than x-range start
        if (el.layout.xaxis.autorange == false) {
            for (var trc = 0; trc < nrTrcs; trc++) {
                while (el.data[[trc]].x[baseX[trc]] < el.layout.xaxis.range[0]) {baseX[trc]++;}
            }   
        }
        // rebase each trace
        for (var trc = 0; trc < nrTrcs; trc++) {
            el.data[trc].y = el.data[[trc]].y.map(x => x / el.data[[trc]].y[baseX[trc]]);
        }
        el.layout.yaxis.autorange = true; // to show all traces if y was zoomed as well
        el.layout.datarevision++; // needs to change for react method to show data changes
        Plotly.react(el, el.data, el.layout);

});
  }
"
htmlwidgets::onRender(pltly, onRenderRebaseTxt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Option 1 works, but Option 2 does not. Possibly some part of the pltly definition is missing as there's also a bracket ")" that's seems should not be there?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the incorrect `(` in the assignment of the `pltly` plot. It is a remnant of my original version, where rebasing is triggered by a custom button. Without the bracket, the code runs fine for me (RStudio Viewer). I uploaded the finished [HTML Version](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aphw_786AT02galsl9DHtF2dr5AeAw?e=vsDpnR)

Comment: after adding the actual rangeslider (`%>% rangeslider()` at the end of pltly definition) it works smoothly, excellent

Comment: I am glad it works for you. Would you mind accepting the solution then? BTW note that in contrast to the `dygraphs` solution, the data in the `plotly` range slider also is rebased. I am not sure how to prevent this.

Comment: How would the htmlwidget solution for rescaling the y-axis work on a plain vanilla (candlestick-)plotly chart work?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with `plotly_relayout` which reads out the visible x-axis range. This is used to recompute the performance. It works as a Shiny app. Here's my code:

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyquant)
library(lubridate)

stocks <- tq_get(c("AAPL", "MSFT"), from = "2019-01-01")

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Rangesliding performance"),
        mainPanel(
           plotlyOutput("plot")
        )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  d <- reactive({ e <- event_data("plotly_relayout")
                  if (is.null(e)) {
                    e$xaxis.range <- c(min(stocks$date), max(stocks$date))
                  }
                  e })

  stocks_range_dyn <- reactive({
    s <- stocks %>%
      group_by(symbol) %>%
      mutate(performance = adjusted/first(adjusted)-1)

    if (!is.null(d())) {
      s <- s %>%
        mutate(performance = adjusted/nth(adjusted, which.min(abs(date - date(d()$xaxis.range[[1]]))))-1)
    }

    s
  })

    output$plot <- renderPlotly({

      plot_ly(stocks_range_dyn(), x = ~date, y = ~performance, color = ~symbol) %>% 
        add_lines() %>%
        rangeslider(start =  d()$xaxis.range[[1]], end =  d()$xaxis.range[[2]], borderwidth = 1)

      })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Definign the start/end of the rangeslider only works with `plot_ly`, not with a ggplot object converted by `ggplotly`. I am unsure if this is a bug, therefore opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1551).